# Unable to use 3 displays (incl. laptop) at the same time

Tags: windows-8.1, display, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, external-display

I have a DELL E6540 with the following specs:

- i7 4610M (supports 3 displays according to Intel)
- AMD Radeon HD 8790M
- Intel HD Graphics 4600
- 1 HDMI port
- 1 VGA port
- Windows 8.1 Enterprise

I think that's sufficient.

I have a setup with a DELL 2414H and SAMSUNG S27E591C and then my laptop's monitor.

The problem is that through Window's display settings I can only extend the desktop to two monitors at a time. So if I have the laptop's monitor activated only one of my external monitors can be used. Both my external monitors work ok.

Why am I restricted to only two monitors when the Intel page says that it supports 3 displays?

I also have an ASUS Ultrabook UX32A with an i7 3537U (intel HD 4000) and no dedicated graphics card, which also supports 3 monitors. With this pc, ALL three monitors show just fine. I can extend all three monitors together.

Is it the AMD graphics card which is causing the problem? I really don't know how to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the Windows display settings, have you looked in the system tray for Intel graphics control panel? It should be installed with the full video driver. You can customize your options there.

Comment: Doesn't provide any more options. I can just see the settings for the laptop display and one of the external displays. Not all three...